# VBA: Worksheet_Change - Target.Address vs Working with Intersect

Tags: excel, vba

I am successfully running a macro that includes the following piece of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        Call MainSub
    End If
End Sub
```

The point of this sub is to make the macro spring into action via calling `MainSub` when Cell B1 or B3 are changed. It works.

However, when looking for a solution on how to do this, I also came across this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call MainSub
    End If
End Sub
```

It works just as well with only B1.

Now I have two questions:

1) How would I include another cell (B3) to check in the intersect method? Using `or` didn't work for me, so  I think another if-Statement after the first one would do the trick, but is there a more elegant solution?

2) What's the advantage of using `intersect` vs simply looking at `Target.Address`?

Comment: The top snippet is implicitly making an assumption about the shape of `Target`; the bottom snippet doesn't make that assumption and will work more reliably.

Comment: Also `Call` is redundant, just `MainSub` is enough to invoke it... and you'll want to set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before and `= True` after, otherwise if `MainSub` decides to modify any cell, then the event handler will be re-entrant (implicit recursion).. and if it modifies cell B1 (or B3), everything bursts up in flames.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon So I put `Application.EnableEvents = False` right before and after `MainSub`? 

I use call because it makes the code more readable to me. With `Call`, I immediately know that another sub is being called, which to me as a beginner isn't always clear otherwise.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents` controls whether or not `Worksheet_Change` gets to run when a cell is modified. You want it set to `False` if running `Worksheet_Change` is going to be modifying any cells, and you want it back to `True` when the event handler exits, so that the next time B1/B3 is modified the handler picks it up. Otherwise `Application.EnableEvents` will just remain `False` after the first invoke, and there won't be a second.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It won't be an issue in this case because those cells won't be touched by the macro, but it sounds like good practice to consider this whenever working with 'Worksheet_Change'. Thanks for pointing it out to me!

Comment: Whether the specific cells are affected or not makes no difference, the event is re-entrant and you want to avoid this and not be one simple conditional statement away from completely crashing everything with uncontrolled implicit recursion... *especially* since whether or not a cell is modified depends on code that is in another procedure / another module. But sure, not an issue *now*.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I think now I got it. It should make the code slower, too, right? At least when it's longer and lots of cells get modified, the code jumps to the `Worksheet_Change` sub every time it happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1,B3")) Is Nothing Then
```

`Intersect` is useful as it will react when multiple cells are changed. For example, if a user copies and pastes data into a range that happens to overlap B1 and/or B3, `Target.Address` will not be `$B$1` or `$B$3`,  but `Intersect` will still work.